# Chrome extension, content script, and XSS attacks

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xss

I've heard dangerous XSS attacks can occur to a website when they allow things like `eval`uating user input JS. I am planning to do something similar for my text expander extension (type some text -> press hotkey -> text expanded).

I will be allowing a user to paste in a plain html string text, and then view it in a nice formatted manner. It is intended for bold, underline, etc. For this I will use `.innerHTML` in a `div`. I very well understand that a malicious user will put evil `<script>` elements in the plain text and try to disrupt my extension. This is what I am concerned about.

**My questions:**

1. My extension will take this html data and paste it in other websites' content editable elements (like gmail; using `innerHTML` with a content script) for text expansion. XSS might affect those sites as well. Should I be concerned about those sites? Imho, it's their responsibility to sanitize their content.
2. My own extension itself does not communicate with *any* servers except the chrome sync storage server, wherein it will store this data in plain text. But, I still do use the `innerHTML` the same way in my `options.html` page (to provide an interactive text expansion playground). Can the XSS affect my extension also in any manner? As per my understanding, they (hackers) will be using a *copy* of the files of my extension on *their own pc* with *their own browser*. I am unable to discern what harm they could cause in this sense.

---

I hope someone with knowledge of how both chrome extensions and XSS work can throw some light. In case I missed any detail/am unclear, do let me know.

**UPDATE:** I just realized that script elements aren't executed through innerHTML, only inline event handlers are. I understand that using CSP helps me prevent inline event handler execution inside my extension. But what about other websites wherein my extension will paste code. Will they also not execute inline event handler js functions?

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for your input! But the MDN page clearly shows that `const name = "<img src='x' onerror='alert(1)'>"; el.innerHTML = name; // shows the alert` can be evil. I think that is what I was concerned about. I will update my question.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you! Sorry to be repetitive with my questions but maybe I'm just not able to get the second thing. "The but won't work on an extension page" I understood that. But will it also not work for the html I insert using a content script on a different website like gmail? Technically, gmail is not an extension page :/

Comment: Well, security-sensitive sites should use CSP that disallows inline js entirely or requires it to be signed via a hash-sum. Anyway, I'm not an expert on XSS so hopefully someone else answers the question entirely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Careless use of `innerHTML` in an extension can lead to several (security) issues, including:

- Same origin bypasses (including universal XSS, aka UXSS).
- Privilege escalation.
- Privacy violations (e.g. referrer leaking).

Your proposed use of innerHTML (taking HTML from untrusted sources and inserting it in a contentEditable element on another site without sanitization) is insecure. In theory, scripts should not execute in **contentEditable** elements, but there have been browser bugs where this is not the case (e.g. [in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=520189) and [in Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=452059)).
For the record - assigning untrusted content to `innerHTML` is unsafe, unless the document is not associated with a view (e.g. such view-less documents can be created with [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) or [`document.implementation.createHTMLDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation/createHTMLDocument)). Note that even though assigning `innerHTML` in such documents is safe, it is **completely unsafe** to insert elements from such documents in documents with a view. See the [XSS article at OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) for general information about XSS.

Privilege escalation may occur when the untrusted content manages to execute in the context of the extension. In content scripts, this is limited to cross-origin network requests and some other extension APIs, in extension pages this includes access to all extension APIs for which the extension has permissions. This has far-reaching consequences and XSS is not uncommon in extensions. For this reason, [Chrome enforces a default content security policy for extensions using `"manifest_version": 2`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifestVersion#manifest-v1-c). This greatly reduces the impact of XSS in extensions, but it is not 100% flawless and you should not use CSP as an excuse to not properly sanitize the data that you assign to `innerHTML`.

(once the dust settles I can share some impactful real-world security incidents with CSP bypasses)

For your specific situation (copying a DOM tree to a contentEditable element in another document), I suggest one of the following approaches:

- Whitelisting: Recursively enumerate all child nodes of an element, and only clone the element if it is a safe element (e.g. "b", "strong", "em", "i", etc.), and only copy the attribute if it is a safe attribute.
- Blacklisting: Deep-clone a subtree, and remove all unsafe elements and unsafe attributes (exercise for the reader: what is an unsafe element? Hint: The answer is not easy, and it depends on the attributes).

If you don't have a DOM tree to start with, parse the HTML using one of the previously suggested methods (e.g. [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)). And be careful in selecting what elements and attributes you choose to accept. For example, [this safeResponse.js file](https://github.com/operatester/safeResponse/blob/1.1/safeResponse.js) seems like a good start (because it removes script tags and all attributes except for some seemingly safe attributes), but it is not. Someone can use the `style` attribute to make the element transparent and on top of the whole document, and then put a `javascript:` link in the `href` attribute (spaces in front of the link are stripped by the browser). When the user clicks anywhere in the page, the script runs in the page's context. [This patch for sendResponse.js](https://github.com/operatester/safeResponse/pull/2/files) fixes the issue, and the result is probably safe against XSS (not safe against privacy violations though, e.g. one can reference external content via CSS in the `style` attribute).

Comment: I'll award you the bounty once you can (1) link to a better alternative to safeResponse.js (2) provide "some impactful real-world security incidents with CSP bypasses". Thank you! :D

Comment: @GaurangTandon (1) With the PR that I proposed, safeResponse.js is safe against XSS in contemporary browsers (unless new dangerous HTML tags are added (in the most extreme case, custom tags can already be potentially dangerous)) (you can also remove "style" from the whitelist to avoid the potential privacy/phishing issue that I described). If you prefer to err on the side of paranoid dcaution, you should use a whitelist-based approach (the answer has also described how you can implement such a whitelist-based HTML sanitizer).

Comment: @GaurangTandon (2) "some impactful real-world security incidents with CSP bypasses". Some of the examples that I have in mind are still confidential, so I can only share that in a few months from now when the details become public (this is what I meant by "once the dust settles"). Here is an example that demonstrates a way to weaken CSP (https://github.com/Synzvato/decentraleyes/issues/130). There are cross-linked bug reports/pull requests at the Angular.js repo, if you are really interested you can follow the links and read about them.

Comment: So DomParser parseFromString is safe?